# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n+(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to find this limit but I'm not sure how can I do it

> Find this limit:
>
> $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n+(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}}$

I analyzed it by this way:

\begin{align}
\underbrace{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left ( \frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}} \right )}_{\text{This must go to zero}} + \underbrace{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left ( \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}} \right )}_{\text{This, also must converge to zero}}
\end{align}

Am I correct? How can I proove it?

Comment: The first limit does not go to zero.

Comment: Divide top and bottom of the original fraction by $2^n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n+(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}}$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{2^n}{2^n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}}{\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2^n}}$$

As $n \to \infty,$ ($\frac{1}{2^n}$ or $\frac{-1}{2^n}) \to0$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{2^n}{2^n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}}{\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2^n}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

The mistake in your method is that the first limit is $1/2$ and not $0$

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n+(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}}
=\frac 1 2\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1+\left(\frac{(-1)}2\right)^{n}}{1+\left(\frac{(-1)}2\right)^{n+1}}\\=\frac1 2$$

We used $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)}2\right)^{n}=0$$ which is true as $\big|\left(\frac{(-1)}2\right)\big|<1$.(which implies geometric series converges which then implies limit of nth term goes to zero.)

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n+(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n+(-1)^{n+1}/2}{2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}} +  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{-(-1)^{n+1}/2 + (-1)^n}{2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}}$$

and:

$$\frac{-1-1}{2^n} <\frac{-(-1)^{n+1}/2 + (-1)^n}{2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}} < \frac{1+1}{2^n}$$

thus by the squeeze theorem, the limit is $\frac{1}{2} + 0 = \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

When $n \to \infty$, the dominant term up is $2^n$ and down it is $2^{n+1}$ so the required limit is $$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}$$